# Reversed result in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get a list of all "Task" documents from my mongoDB in a reverse order, so latest added "Tasks" are first in the list.

Is there a smart way of doing that?

```
allTasks(){
  return Task.find(function (err, allTasks) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    return allTasks;
  })
}
```

UPDATE
Following code solves the problem:

```
allTasks(){
return Task.find().sort({created_at:-1}).exec(function (err, allTasks) {
if (err) return console.error(err);
con
return allTasks;})
}
```

Comment: YousefM, when presenting code in your question, use the '{}' (code sample) button in the question bar to format relevant code blocks. Do this instead of posting a picture/screen shot of code

Comment: use `sort({<dateadded>:-1})` in your options parameter while searching

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked:) @wrangler

Comment: Sorry that was my first ever post in stackoverflow. Thank you, I will remember that in future questions. @AlekPiasecki

Comment: @YousefM no problem man! Just letting you know!